# Process for Determining Accuracy of Polygon

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, javascript

What tools/processing/decision trees would one use to get a base line of the accuracy of a polygon? I'll explain below.

In my line of work, I deal with buffered lines (polygons) and I'd like to create a process to determine how far the furthest edge of that buffered line are from it's centerline. The problem I'm running into is that I have some polygons that exhibit a linear pattern similar to it's centerline, but then I have others that cover very large surface areas and do not represent a linear pattern much at all. I'm having trouble generating any semblance of a centerline from polygons that don't exhibit a strong linear pattern Below are a couple of examples:

Linear tendency:
[image]

Non-linear tendency:
[image]

Can you provide any thoughts or direction on some form of a standardized approach to solving this problem?

I am fluent in Python/PostGIS/QGIS/JS.

Also I tried using the [Centerline](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline) library but I kept getting an error saying the number of produced ridges is to small.

Comment: Now that your question has a PostGIS answer I think you should focus it on that. You can always ask about the other GIS software products in separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of the **Maximum Inscribed Circle** provides the largest distance from a point on the medial axis (centreline) to the polygon boundary.  In PostGIS this is provided by [`ST_MaximumInscribedCircle`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/ST_MaximumInscribedCircle.html).